# VS2005 IDE: Automatically accept code change suggestions?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2005

I'm pasting test data from a SQL results into my code.  I'm using the SQL results to manually populate a strongly typed dataset.  However, the data types need to be casted to the correct data types.  VS2005 tells me that I need to cast each field as an int, decimal, date, etc., but I'd rather not have to click this hundreds of times or manually write the casts each time.

Is there a shortcut to do something like navigate to the next error, then another shortcut to accept the code suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, ReSharper can do this with Alt+PgDn, Alt+Enter, Enter, rinse-and-repeat. I dare say that other VS plugins have similar features.